# Is the addEventListener method part of the document object?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure where the addEventListener comes from but I assume that it is part of the document object. If so, would the code `document.getElementById('displayTodosButton').addEventListener`
work that same as `var displayTodosButton = document.getElementById('displayTodosButton');`?

```
 var displayTodosButton = document.getElementById('displayTodosButton');

    displayTodosButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
      todoList.displayTodos();
    });
```

Comment: Sure those two variations work the same ... and that is basic JS, and has nothing to do with addEventListener specifically. With `foo.bar()` and `var baz = foo; baz.bar();` it would be the same thing.

Comment: `addEventListener` is a method provided by any `HTMLElement` of the DOM. `document.getElementById()` returns an `HTMLElement`, so you can call `addEventListener` on it without using a variable as intermediate, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be any object that supports events: "The event target may be an Element in a document, the Document itself, a Window, or any other object that supports events (such as XMLHttpRequest)."

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

`document.getElementById('displayTodosButton').addElementListener` would not work, because the method's called `addEventListener`. Other than that, you're free to save a reference to the element in a variable or directly use it when returned from `.getElementById()`. The result won't be different.